# Moving Drives Between Macs

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, hard-drive, migration

I'm considering buying a new MacBook Pro after today's refresh, and I am wondering if OS X handles simply pulling a drive out of one MacBook Pro and putting it in another. I know that in the Windows world this is — most of the time — possible, but I have never tried it with OS X. Does the OS handle the sudden change in hardware, or does it 'sh*t bricks' and abort mission? In theory you'd think it could handle it, but anyone with definite experience would be good.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this is a very safe, OS X boots other hardware in general situation.

However, when new hardware is released - often a special build is made and until the next revision or two of software, you can't boot that hardware so you'd need to take a hard drive from the specialized machine to an older one instead of the other way around.

It's far safer to migrate from a Time Machine or target mode or from running OS using file sharing / network. That way each machine has the correct OS and can flag apps or system files for non-transfer when there is a known problem migrating them.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, the new drive is larger than the old, no? Certainly younger, and harddrives have a failure rate that rises with age.
I suggest you use migration assistant and just move the data over to the new machine.